# jQuery style Constructors in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class-constructors

Is there a way to instantiate a new PHP object in a similar manner to those in jQuery?  I'm talking about assigning a variable number of arguments when creating the object.  For example, I know I could do something like:

```
...
//in my Class
__contruct($name, $height, $eye_colour, $car, $password) {
...
}

$p1 = new person("bob", "5'9", "Blue", "toyota", "password");
```

But I'd like to set only some of them maybe.  So something like:

```
$p1 = new person({
    name: "bob",
    eyes: "blue"});
```

Which is more along the lines of how it is done in jQuery and other frameworks.  Is this built in to PHP?  Is there a way to do it?  Or a reason I should avoid it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby-like array arguments implementation in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870501/ruby-like-array-arguments-implementation-in-php)

Comment: Here is a workaround (including a description of its downsides): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112913

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best method to do this is using an array:

```
class Sample
{
    private $first  = "default";
    private $second = "default";
    private $third  = "default";

    function __construct($params = array())
    {
         foreach($params as $key => $value)
         {
              if(isset($this->$key))
              {
                  $this->$key = $value; //Update
              }
         }
    }
}
```

And then construct with an array

```
$data = array(
     'first' => "hello"
     //Etc
);
$Object = new Sample($data);
```

Comment: Not what he wants, though. He wants to use *named* arguments that can be specified in arbitrary order

Comment: Yea i was in the middle of updating :/

Comment: The update has a bunch of good information.  +1.  (Although I would personally provide defaults to the parameters rather than leaving them null)...

Answer (score 2):

```
class foo {
   function __construct($args) {
       foreach($args as $k => $v) $this->$k = $v;
       echo $this->name;
    }
 }

 new foo(array(
    'name' => 'John'
 ));
```

The closest I could think of.

If you want to be more fancy and just want to allow certain keys, you can use `__set()` (**only** on php 5)

```
var $allowedKeys = array('name', 'age', 'hobby');
public function __set($k, $v) {
   if(in_array($k, $this->allowedKeys)) {
      $this->$k = $v;
   }
}
```

Comment: Variable Variables?  Inside of a class?  Really?  Why not use `$this->$k` instead of `$$k`?  Decent idea, wrong implementation... If you were going to do that, why not just use [`extract`](http://us2.php.net/extract)?  -1...

Answer (score 0):

get args won't work as PHP will see only one argument being passed.

```
public __contruct($options) {
    $options = json_decode( $options );
    ....
    // list of properties with ternary operator to set default values if not in $options
    ....
}
```

have a looksee at [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Using json is nonsensical in this instance. (A native array wouldn't need to be needlessly en/decoded.)

Comment: agreed - but just addressing the OPs initial request.  No need to encode json to pass in object instantiation but would always need decode.

Answer (score -1):

The closest I can think of is to use `array()` and [`extract()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

```
...
//in your Class
__contruct($options = array()) {

    // default values
    $password = 'password';
    $name = 'Untitled 1';
    $eyes = '#353433';

    // extract the options
    extract ($options);

    // stuff
    ...

}
```

And when creating it.

```
$p1 = new person(array(
    'name' => "bob",
    'eyes' => "blue"
));
```